# .NET Core add migration ignoring some properties

Tags: mysql, migration, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm trying to run some migrations but it seems to ignore some properties.

Here is the Model that has the ignored property:

```
 public class UserRoleModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    internal long Id { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public long RoleId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "TIMESTAMP(6)")]
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "TIMESTAMP(6)")]
    public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }

    public RoleModel Role { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }

}
```

The DeleteDate property gets ignored. My UserModel has the same property with the same annotation but it gets added just fine.

This is what the migration builder creates:

```
         migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UsersRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                UserId = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<long>(nullable: false),
                Active = table.Column<ulong>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "true"),
                AddDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)")
            },
```

The modelbuilder in the Context:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleModel>().ToTable("UsersRoles").HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleModel>().Property(b => b.Active).HasDefaultValueSql("true");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleModel>().Property(b => b.AddDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

The only thing this model/entity has that others don't is that it includes foreign keys.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleModel>().HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(y => y.UsersRoles).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleModel>().HasOne(x => x.Role).WithMany(y => y.UsersRoles).HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId);
```

But that's the only difference.
DbSet name for good measure:

```
        public DbSet<UserRoleModel> UsersRoles { get; set; }
```

I've deleted the migrations a few times over, but it keeps on adding the same exact code. Does anyone know what can create this behavior?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.What is the version of your EF Core?

Comment: Could you share more details about your model and DbContext?

Comment: tried this `modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleModel>().Property(x => x.DeleteTime).HasColumnName("DeleteTime");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this issue in `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` version `3.0.1`.

I used the following code to test this, which works as expected:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class UserRoleModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "TIMESTAMP(6)")]
        public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "TIMESTAMP(6)")]
        public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserRoleModel> UsersRoles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=so59180050")
                .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(b => b
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then a ran the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --verbose
```

It generated the following Migration:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "UsersRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    AddDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TIMESTAMP(6)", nullable: false),
                    DeleteDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TIMESTAMP(6)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_UsersRoles", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "UsersRoles");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mine is running 3.0.0. Maybe that tiny update will fix the issue. Or maybe some other NuGet package is being difficult. Thanks for trying it out!

Comment: No, this is not related to the 3.0.0 -> 3.0.1 update (I tested it on 3.0.0 as well) and this should not be related to dependencies either. This is likely an issue in your project. I suggest that you run my test code to ensure that it works on your end as well. Then either simplify your own project until it works and pinpoint the problem this way, or provide us with a working example project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also probably check for additional Fluent API calls.

Comment: Updated everything to 3.0.1 (Pomelo, Tools and Designer) and now it works. Reverted back to 3.0.0, still works. Microsoft Magic?